# Connect Redis to Docker-compose

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, redis, docker

I've setup my docker to connect with redis. But upon running the application i'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CredisException: 
Connection to Redis redis:0 failed after 2 failures.
Last Error : (111) Connection refused in /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php:475 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(471): Credis_Client->connect() 
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(784): Credis_Client->connect() 
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(637): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array) 
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(382): Credis_Client->select(1) 
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(243): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->_applyClientOptions(Object(Credis_Client)) 
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array) 
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) 
#7 /var/www/ht in /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php on line 475
```

Not sure where to modify. Maybe someone here can help me? This is the configuration I have for my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web:
    image: alexcheng/magento2
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "32823:22"
    env_file:
      - env
    environment:
      - WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=local.domain.com
      - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html
      - PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=EST
      - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
      - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
      - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
      - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
      - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=1024M
    volumes:
      - "./project:/var/www/html"
    container_name: web
    links:
      - db
      - redis
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    container_name: mariadb
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    env_file:
      - env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_local_db
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8580:80"
    links:
      - db     
    container_name: phpmyadmin    
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
volumes:
  db-data: 
    external: false 
  redis-data:
    external: false
```

And this is the content of my `env.php` file under `app/etc/`

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => 'MY_KEY_HERE'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'db',
                'dbname' => 'my_local_db',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'password',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => ''
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'port' => '',
                    'database' => '1',
                    'compress_data' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => 'redis',
            'port' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '2.5',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '2',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '1',
            'max_concurrency' => '6',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '0',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
        ]
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'vertex' => 1
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Wed, 09 Jan 2019 12:54:30 +0000'
    ]
];
```

Hope someone can help me with this...

Update:
I tried removing this code in `app/etc/env.php` and it was running

```
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => 'redis',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => ''
            ]
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => 'redis',
                'port' => '',
                'database' => '1',
                'compress_data' => '0'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

I'm not sure what this does or how important this is because I just copied this in one of the tutorial [here](https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento-2-tutorials/redis-for-local-magento-2-development/)

Comment: I just created an answer below. Btw, this looks like a modified version of the docker recipe I offer on my blog. Just curious, is it? https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento-2-tutorials/docker-magento-2-development/

Comment: What if you go inside your `php-fpm` and try curl to `redis:6379`? What will it say? Your docker-compose file looks fine, maybe try to add port into your `env.php`?

Comment: With a link in the docker-compose.yml you shouldn't need to specify the port for redis. I don't and my setup is very similar.

Comment: If you've already removes the additional "links" node can you update the docker-compose sample in your question to more accurately reflect the current state of your setup?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson yes it's a modified version as I wanted to make use of your sample and another one from other sources that I found. Will update the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Cool! Im glad to see people making use of it. Which version of Magento are you running on your docker setup?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson I'm running version 2.3.0

Comment: Perfect, please see my updated answer. I am actively working on 2.3 ce right this minute. I'll also post the docker-compose.yml in a moment

Comment: @ShawnAbramson is this in the same tutorial for redis? Will look into this then

Comment: My updated answer includes my unmodified env.php and docker-compose.yml for a vanilla M2 2.3.0 setup with Redis enabled. I created a new CLI command to do this automatically so I don't have to copy and paste from my own tut each time. The CLI command is based on the original tutorial with some minor changes.

Comment: https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento2-freebies/magento2-docker-vm-script/

Comment: @ShawnAbramson thanks for this will try it out

Comment: @MadzQuestioning did you sort this out? I am having this issue too

Comment: @vnpnlz not yet.. I have installed other approach and decided to go with Vagrant instead of docker

Answer (score 0):

In your web service, **you have two links nodes**. Delete the first one sitting under the ports mapping. Everything else looks correct.

What's happening is that the first links node is being used and so docker never realizes you're creating a link to your redis service.

Delete that and then docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build and you should be golden.

Further to our discussion in the comments section, I am posting the full contents of the env.php file from the 2.3 CE site I happen to be working on at the moment. Please note that port is not actually required with this setup but I created a cli script to generate this and it puts the port in there.

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => '67c754d8850edfa7204d7b3c545b9d24'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'mysql',
                'dbname' => 'qbo',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => 'redis',
            'port' => '6379',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '2.5',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '2',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '1',
            'max_concurrency' => '6',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '0',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000',
            'sentinel_master' => '',
            'sentinel_servers' => '',
            'sentinel_connect_retries' => '5',
            'sentinel_verify_master' => '0'
        ]
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379'
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'database' => '1',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'compress_data' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'vertex' => 1
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Fri, 15 Mar 2019 15:24:56 +0000'
    ],
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'dev' => [
                'debug' => [
                    'debug_logging' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.2
        container_name: qbo_web
        user: application
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - "/Users/shawn/Websites/Magento2/qbo:/app:cached"
          - "root-ssh-files:/root/.ssh/"
          - "user-ssh-files:/home/application/.ssh/"
        environment:
          - WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=local.qbo.com
          - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/pub
          - PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=EST
          - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
          - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
          - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
          - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
          - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=1024M
          - PHP_DEBUGGER=xdebug
          - XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK=0
          - XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=10.200.10.1
          - XDEBUG_REMOTE_PORT=9000
          - php.xdebug.remote_enable=1
          - php.xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
        ports:
          - "443:443"
          - "32834:22"
        links:
          - mysql
          - redis
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10
        container_name: qbo_mysql
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=qbo
        ports:
          - "33067:3306"
        command: [
            '--wait_timeout=28800',
            '--max_allowed_packet=32505856'
        ]
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
        container_name: qbo_redis
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"
        volumes:
          - redis-data:/data
volumes:
    db-data:
        external: false
    root-ssh-files:
        external: false
    user-ssh-files:
        external: false
    redis-data:
        external: false
```

Comment: Already did that and the error is a connection refused. I think this is not the problem because if web service does not realize there is a redis then "I think" the error should not be connection refused?

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Just type Redis port and let us know

Answer (score 0):

I can read from the error log "unable to connect to redis:0". In my opinion your env.php is lacking default redis port, 6379. Just update your app/etc/env.php with default redis port (6379) instead of a blank ''..this should fix